# Physic of a floating burning candle in water (Archimedes principle)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, buoyancy

my cousin got this question in an exam and we have absolutely no idea how we are supposed to find the answer. The exam is already over, but we are still curious about the answer.

The length of a candle floating in water is $\ell$, the diameter is $d$, the thickness of the candle is constant and there is a stone with mass $m$ at the bottom of the candle. The candle is floating still straight up in the container. The length of the candle that's above the waterline is $h$, once the candle is ignited, the speed at which it burns is $v$. When $h$ is 0 (when the candle meets the waterline), the flame is extinguished. The melted wax is ignored (consider it gone from the universe when melted) and the mass and density of the wick is negligible. The density of water is $p$w and the density of the candle is $p$c.

[image]

Q: How long does the candle burn for? Answer in formula

Comment: From what you know about the physics of the problem (assume v is constant) : what is causing it to float, what would cause it to sink, where would those two aspects be equal in value, what have you tried, and how would you suggest to approach the probem?